# Dynamic Data source in MS PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Is there a way to have different MS excel data sources based on users who is logged in and the team to which he belongs to?
I have checked the community forum and in there it is mentioned that MS Powerapps doesn't provide any in-built feature for this use case.
Does anyone know of any workarounds?

Comment: What are you trying to do and how many users will there be?

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible in a straight forward way.

I would recommend you to build a separate App for each team/persona - this will be easy to maintain.

Otherwise, you have to maintain a separate list for User/Team - Datasource (connection string) mapping and from there you should load data. You can get idea from this [blog post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connecting-datasource-dynamically-in-power-apps-using-power-automate-part-2/)